# Calling custom Block in the transactional emails

Tags: magento-1.9, transactional-mail

This is how I call a custom phtml file in the trans.email content:

```
{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='foldername/myfile.phtml' order=$order}}
```

and its working perfect. But I want to include a block where I will do the logic and in the phtml file I just want to call the needed function from my block. 
I tried the following:

```
{{block type='mynamespace_mymodule/email_pdflink' area='frontend' template='foldername/myfile.phtml' order=$order}}
```

and this is the content of the block:

```
class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Email_Pdflink extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function test()
    {
        return 13;
    }
}
```

and the content of the myfile.phtml:

```
$this->test();
```

Even if a write a simple html code in the myfile.phtml file it doesn't show up in the content of my trans. email. Any idea  how to solve this ? thx

Comment: Please paste the code for your config.xml as well.

Comment: May be the error is the line {{block type='mynamespace_mymodule/email_pdflink' area='frontend' template='foldername/myfile.phtml' order=$order}} type attribute

Comment: in the config the blocks field is loaded. The attribute value it should be correct. Do you have some suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is allow the custom class directive for your block in
*System > Permissions > Blocks*

Just add the class directive and set to 1.

I was implementing something similar recently and it has to do with a recentish patch (SUPEE-6788). Spent some time testing and going crazy until I realized this was the issue.

More information can be found on the mage site about the patch
https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788-technical-details